# Health status of Dracaena deremensis

Tags: plant-health, dracaena

I'm new to maintaining plants and want to cultivate caring for plants. I find that every so often, a couple of leaves at the bottom turn brown, and I prune them off. I also find that some leaves show partial wilting, especially close to their tips, as seen here.

[image: plant]

As for caring for the plant, I water it once every two days. It doesn't receive direct sunlight but does receive scattered sunlight.

Would like to get your recommendations on how to meet the demands of this plant and make any changes that would help plant live healthily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you overwater the plant now with once every two days water. Try to reduce that to once every two weeks, instead of days. Try to give it a full load of water then, and remove surplus water (that is collected in outer pot) after say about half an hour.

Scattered light should be fine for this plant, but the yellowing and eventually browning leaves are most likely a sign of too much water.